# Access AWS Network Load Balancer from VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC with current subnets:

1. `public-subnet` has access to Internet Gateway:

```
 routing public: 
    172.31.0.0/16 -> local
    0.0.0.0/0 -> igw
```

2. `private-subnet` has NAT Gateway:

```
routing private: 
    172.31.0.0/16 -> local
    0.0.0.0/0 -> nat
```

3. `internal-subnet` have access to Internet Gateway:

```
routing internal: 
    172.31.0.0/16 -> local
    0.0.0.0/0 -> nat
```

My Lambda function is deployed in a private subnet. In `internal-subnet` deployed network balancer and ecs task. I want to make requests from my lambda in `private-subnet` to network load balancer.

I tried different approaches but always get timeouts. I tried to make request bu private task IP  but still getting timeouts.

How to configure access from one subnet to load balancer in another subnet inside VPC?

Comment: check your route table.

Comment: Is the Network Load Balancer configured as `Internet-facing` or `Internal`? An internal load balancer routes requests to targets using private IP addresses. It sounds like your Lambda function is attempting to access the Load Balancer via a **public** IP address.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein In load balancer config I see `scheme: Internal`

Comment: In that case, check the Security Group associated with the ECS task. You should have two security groups: One on the Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`) with no configuration change, and another on the ECS task (`Task-SG`) that permits inbound traffic from `Lambda-SG`. A Network Load Balancer does not use security group -- it just passes the request through to the target and the target's security group is used.